# First redirect, then substitute using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My goal is:

1. user visits the url - http://example.com/index.php?order_result=1&orderID=1500638
2. the address is transformed into - http://example.com/order/success.php?id=1500638
   with no actual redirection, 'cause there's no "http://example.com/order/success.php" script on server.
3. by visiting the url 'http://example.com/order/success.php?id=1500638' user gets data from the first script - http://example.com/index.php?order_result=1&orderID=1500638.
   so there was no actual redirection, the url address was substituted (url address in the browser window changed) and the resulting data retrieved from the requested url.

This is what I managed to achieve:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^order_placement_result=([0-9]+)&orderID=(.*)$
RewriteRule index\.php /order/success.php?id=%2 [C,N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/order/success.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/order/success.php?id=([0-9]+)$ /index.php?order_placement_result=1&orderID=$1 [L]
```

/update: forgot to tell that the problem in my script is in the last line. i tested it using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
don't understand what the problem is!

it blows my mind! please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a classic infinite loop problem. Besides that, there are a couple of things I want to clear up:

- You can only change the url that is displayed in the address bar of a browser by redirecting the user. You need to use the `R` flag to do this
- `.htaccess` is ran before any script is executed. If you have a file `test.php` on your server, a rule `RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /foo [R]` in your .htaccess and go to http://example.com/test.php, the script test.php will never be run, because Apache will redirect the user to `/foo` before it gets to a point where it will run the script.
- The infinite loop problem in mod_rewrite is when the result of one rule can be matched by an other rule, and the result of that rule can be matched by the first rule. What you want to accomplish is possible though; you just have to approach it differently.
- The `N` flag will not solve logical problems with your .htaccess. It will circumvent the automatic limit on internal recursion though, possibly crashing Apache and creating a giant error log. It is only useful in a very marginal amount of cases. Consider using just `[L]` with a bigger limit for `LimitInternalRecursion` if you really need to. It will save you nightmares when you overlooked something and Apache crashes constantly due to some unexpected url.
- The first argument of `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` will only match everything after the pathname `/` and before the query string. If your `.htaccess` is in your document root, it will match `test.php` in the url `http://example.com/test.php?id=3`. If you try to match `^/` it will never ever match anything, since the leading slash is always included in the path name.

---

You need to have 2 rules. One of the rules is the external redirect that changes the browser url. The other rule is the internal rewrite that changes the pretty url back to the 'ugly' url. To prevent the redirect loop, you'll need to match the external request (`%{THE_REQUEST}`) instead, since this doesn't change even if you rewrite the internal representation.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

#External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?order_placement_result=([0-9]+)&orderID=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /order/success.php?id=%3 [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^order/success\.php$ /index.php?order_placement_result=1&orderID=$1 [L]
```

Please note that this is untested, but if I didn't mess up too bad it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution works like a charm! Also, thanks for editing my post (English is not my native language and I'm lack of practice)